# How to get ESLint to only process .ts files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I want ESLint skip processing .js files and only deal with .ts files.

To that end, I created `.eslintignore` and added:

```
*.js
**/*.js
```

However, it seems like ESLint ignores this file.  Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Did you create it in the correct directory?

Comment: @Aplet123 I placed the file in the same folder as .eslintrc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the other typescript-eslint config is configured, you have to explicitly tell ESLint you want to include those file extensions:

```
eslint <path to files> --ext ts
```